# AWS SDK issues with DynamoDB and putItem

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to use the `aws-sdk` to interact with AWS' dynamodb

Here is my code:

```
DynamoDB.putItem({
    "TableName": tblName,
    "Item": {
        "UserId": { "N": obj.user_id.toString() },
        "Identifier": { "S": obj.identifier },
        "ReferralToken": { "S": obj.referral_token },
        "CampaignId": { "N": obj.campaign_id.toString() },
        "FirstName": { "S": obj.first_name },
        "LastName": { "S": obj.last_name },
        "Gender": { "S": obj.gender },
        "BirthDate": { "S": obj.birthdate },
        "Username": { "S": obj.username },
        "MobileNumber": { "S": obj.mobile_number },
        "PostalCodeText": { "S": obj.postal_code_text },
        "Classification": { "S": obj.classification },
        "DeliveryEmail": { "S": obj.delivery_email.toString() },
        "DeliverySMS": { "S": obj.delivery_sms.toString() }
    }
}, function (err, data) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```

The error I am receiving is

```
{ [ValidationException: Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes]
  message: 'Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes',
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: Fri Oct 10 2014 10:15:25 GMT-0500 (CDT),
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false }
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Error say supplied attribute is empty, can you just check all the values coming from "obj" are not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Put Item](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) documentation,

> When you add an item, the primary key attribute(s) are the only required attributes. Attribute values cannot be null. String and Binary type attributes must have lengths greater than zero. Set type attributes cannot be empty. Requests with empty values will be rejected with a `ValidationException` exception.

So make sure all values are non-null, and that all string lengths are greater than zero.

Comment: I had same issue and cause was my string length was "Zero"

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I got the same issue because of invalid parameter sends from mapping template.

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{ 
   "userId": "$input.params('userId')",
   "userEmail": "$input.params('userEmail')",
   "userName": "$input.params('userName')",
   "userPassword": "$input.params('userPassword')"
}
```

Here I sent extra parameter userId , that's why error occurred .
So please check your mapping template , May be possible your doing same .