# AWS DynamoDB issue with PutItem. What's the proper JSON format?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, validationerror

I'm having trouble sending PutItem requests through to DynamoDB. I understand that a similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302699/aws-sdk-issues-with-dynamodb-and-putitem), but it seems I have no empty values here.

My JSON is:

```
{
    "TableName":"Unity",
    "Item":{
        "id":{
            "S":"73709359-ac78-46a0-8ca6-414393e33339"
        },
        "Session":{
            "S":"b6ba8b6d-ce27-4585-aee5-b9a2393e54da"
        },
        "Pos":{
            "X":{
                "S":"-16.8"
            },
            "Y":{
                "S":"-4.492812"
            }
        },
        "Time":{
            "S":"7/27/2017 3:21:25 PM"
        }
    }
}
```

And the error is a ValidationException:

```
Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code. I have added the data type **Map** for attribute `Pos`.

```
var dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB;

var params = {
    TableName: "Unity",
    Item: {
        "id": {
            S: "73709359-ac78-46a0-8ca6-414393e33339"
        },
        "Session": {
            S: "b6ba8b6d-ce27-4585-aee5-b9a2393e54da"
        },
        "Pos": {
            M: {
                "X": {
                    S: "-16.8"
                },
                "Y": {
                    S: "-4.492812"
                }
            }
        },
        "Time": {
            S: "7/27/2017 3:21:25 PM"
        }
    }
};

console.log("Adding a new item...");
dynamoDB.putItem(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
            null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```